# Is STL a part of core of c++?

Tags: c++, stl

I have some confusing True and False questions 
I wish anyone answers them and prove the answer for me because I already did a search

1 - STL is a part of the core of c++ programming language

2 - std::string is a part of STL **(I guess T)**

3 - One purpose of the iterator is to connect containers and algorithms **(I guess T)**

4 - Elements of a list are stored sequentially in a memory. **(I guess F)**

5 - Elements of a vector are stored sequentially in a memory. **(I guess F)**

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "STL"? People use it loosely to mean slightly different things and answering your question correctly depends on agreeing a meaning for "STL".

Comment: Nice question. My answer would be T, T, T, F?, T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) and (2) both depend on your definitions.  "The STL" is technically not part of standard C++, but sufficiently large portions of it were adapted into the original standard that the name stuck.  But yes, the templated containers commonly reffered to as the STL are part of the official, standard C++ library.  "Core" might be a stretch; a compiler can actually leave them out of freestanding implementation, but you're almost never going to find yourself writing for a freestanding implementation so the distinction doesn't really matter.

(3) <strike>Do they serve any other purpose?</strike> Yes, that is one purpose.  As Steve Jessop points out below, they also connect things like streams, that can be iterated without actually being a container, to algorithms.

(4) Are you referring to `std::list`?  Then you are correct.  Unless you want to play with semantics; they are stored sequentially, but maybe not contiguously.

(5) In the original standard, published in '98, this would have been a maybe.  In the modified standard from '03, this got changed to a yes.  In both cases, the semantic argument from (4) can also be applied

Comment: Answer to your rhetorical question in (3) is "yes". They also serve to connect algorithms with things that are iterable but are not containers, such as streams ;-) So it's one purpose but not the only purpose.

Comment: @Steve: Fair enough, I had forgotten about those.

Comment: Also as a point of history, I believe that `string` was not part of the first versions of the STL, but was incorporated into the STL by SGI before it was finalized/stabilized/abandoned/whatever they called it. Certainly it's part of its current documented form (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/). So on the "technically not part of standard C++" definition of STL, `string` is in.

Comment: Note: not all STL containers are in the C++ standard. `rope` and `slist` are examples.

Comment: Elements of an `std::list` are not stored sequentially. They are stored wherever the memory allocator decides to put them. The last element of a list may well be (and often will be) before the first element in memory.

Answer (score 3):

I think answers given by ALS are correct. To elaborate more on your first question - 
From the book Thinking in C++ by Bruce Eckel -

> There is often a bit of confusion between the containers and algorithms in the Standard C++ Library, and the entity known as the STL. The Standard Template Library was the name Alex Stepanov (who was working at Hewlett-Packard at the time) used when he presented his library to the C++ Standards Committee at the meeting in San Diego, California in Spring 1994. The name stuck, especially after HP decided to make it available for public downloads. Meanwhile, the committee integrated it into the Standard C++ Library, making a large number of changes. STL's development continues at Silicon Graphics (SGI; see http://www.sgi.com/Technology/STL). The SGI STL diverges from the Standard C++ Library on many subtle points. So although it's a popular misconception, the C++ Standard does not “include” the STL. It can be a bit confusing since the containers and algorithms in the Standard C++ Library have the same root (and usually the same names) as the SGI STL. In this book, I will say “The Standard C++ Library” or “The Standard Library containers,” or something similar and will avoid the term “STL.”

Comment: although your answer doesn't cover all questions, it is an interesting information, so +1

Comment: I did not answer all the questions because I mention in my first sentence that I think answers given by ALS are correct. Thanks for uponeing my answer though :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are my answers:

```
False  
True  
True
False  
True
```

Answer (score 0):

My answers:

1. True -- You can't have C++ without STL
2. True -- It's documented to be so everywhere
3. True -- Sounds reasonable
4. False -- No, it's a linked list
5. True -- Yes, it's an array-based list

Comment: You have to be careful with the definition. The problem is that STL has entered common usage but not the standard. Technically the STL was defined before the standard and the standard used huge chunks of the STL (but not all of it). So technically STL is not part of the standard. See www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ where the original STL documentation lives (written by the creator of the STL). Here you will find Rope (and other classes) yet this is not part of the C++ standard (though it (rope) will be soon).

Answer (score 0):

1. it is a part of a standard library, but its implementation is not covered by standard.
2. probably yes
3. probably yes, but their main purpose is to abstract a programmer from some container implementation and to generalize all collections
4. no, this is not guaranteed at all! 95 from 100 that it is not in your implementation
5. yes

Comment: (5): it is guaranteed since C++03, 23.2.4/1, "The elements of a
vector are stored contiguously, meaning that ..."

Answer (score 0):

std::string is *not* a part of the Standard Template Library. The strings, the STL, and some other miscellaneous things collectively form the C++ standard library. The STL comprises containers, iterators, algorithms, and function objects. It has a specific meaning because it has a specific origin: SGI's template library.